# Can't use Wi-Fi and LAN at the same time

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, ethernet

I have a macbook and a belkin USB-C to Ethernet Adapter. I would like to use Wi-Fi to access the internet, and the LAN cable to connect to a local network. But it doesn't work. Whenever I plug in the LAN cable, I can't access the internet anymore, and no Wi-Fi networks are found. Why is that?

I set the LAN configuration manually:
IP address: 10.0.4.7
netmask: 255.255.255.0
The router field is empty.
I tried changing the network priorities, this doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: It should still be under apple warranty if you wanted to take it to an Apple Store I think.  I have heard a lot of issues like these on the newer macs.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the priority for Wi-Fi over LAN connection. By default machines have LAN connection at top priority. You choose Wi-Fi at top and try again.

Step to change the priority of connection;

1. Go to **System Preference -> Network**, in network section at left-below side you have three icons +,-,(icon for setting).
2. Click on setting icon and you will get multiple option.
3. Select "Set Service Order..."
4. Then you will be prompt to a new window with all network option.
5. Select Wi-Fi and drag it to top.

It should help you to get your internet connection back. Please let me know if it works.